# Simulating a transient error for Service Bus

Tags: servicebus

I'm writing an application which will use the Azure Service Bus. For local development I'm using Windows Server Service Bus to provide the same services (the code to use either is identical).

I want to write the application to be tolerant of transient errors when sending or receiving messages. To that end, I want to be able to test the fault-handling code can deal with the local Service Bus instance suddenly being unavailable during execution of various operations.

Ideally, I'd want to write some automated integration tests around these scenarios, but I appreciate that may not be practically achieved.

What can I do to simulate transient errors on my local Service Bus?

Answer (score 1):

One easy thing would be to call the stop-sbservice (affects one node) or stop-sbfarm (affects the entire farm) cmdlets. This would let you simulate a servicebus outage locally. You can then call start-sbservice or start-sbfarm to bring the service back and validate that your code recovers properly. This approach also has the added benefit that you control when the service returns (compare to just crashing the process). [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj200653%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) has information on the available cmdlets.

If that's not enough, another approach that I've used in the past is to shut down the network interface, or, if the server is in another machine, put up a firewall on the ports used to communicate to service bus.